# Area of square inside a triangle

Tags: triangles, area

Considering the attached image, please compute the area of the square.

$\\$To elaborate suppose we have a triangle $\Delta ABC$, that its angle $\angle ABC$ is equal to $45^o$. On side $\overline{AB}$ we have a point $E$ that divide the side to two segments, $\overline{BE}=4$ and $\overline{EA}=6$.

> Find the area of the square $\square CDEF$, such that its $\overline{FC}$ side reside on $\overline{AC}$ side of the triangle $\Delta ABC$, its one vertex is on **E** point, and the alternate vertex of **E** is on vertex **C**.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: From the text, there could be a solution where $\angle ACB$ is acute and $D$ is outside $\triangle ABC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\angle ACE &= 45^\circ\\
\triangle ABC &\sim \triangle ACE\\
\frac{AC}{AB} &= \frac{AE}{AC}\\
{AC}^2 &= 60
\end{align*}
$$

Consider $\triangle ACE$, taking sine law and considering only the case where $\angle AEC = \angle ACB$ are obtuse,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin\angle AEC}{AC} &= \frac{\sin \angle ACE}{AE}\\
\sin\angle AEC &= \frac{AC\sin\angle ACE}{AE}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt {60}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt2}}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{30}}{6}\\
\cos\angle AEC &= \color{red}-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\angle AEC}\\
&= \color{red}-\frac{\sqrt6}{6}
\end{align*}$$

The area of the square can be found from side $EF = AE\cos \angle AEF$:

$$\begin{align*}
(AE\cos \angle AEF)^2 &= {AE}^2 \cos^2(\angle AEC-45^\circ)\\
&= {AE}^2\cdot \frac{1+\cos 2(\angle AEC-45^\circ)}{2}\\
&= {AE}^2\cdot \frac{1+\cos (2\angle AEC-90^\circ)}{2}\\
&= {AE}^2\cdot \frac{1+\sin 2\angle AEC}{2}\\
&=\frac{6^2}2\left[1+2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{30}}{6}\left(\color{red}-\frac{\sqrt6}{6}\right)\right]\\
&= 18 \color{red}- 6\sqrt5
\end{align*}$$

If otherwise consider an acute $\angle ACB$ and flip the red $\color{red}-$ sign, this gives another solution.

Comment: Thank you, it was the answer I understood.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In $\triangle BCE$, $D$ is the circumcenter. Can you see why?

So $BD = CD = DE$ and $\angle BED = \angle A$.

So you can easily see that $\sin 2A = \frac{2}{3}$ and area of the square is $36 \sin^2A = 18(1-\cos 2A)$

Comment: Finding $\sin 2A$ does not require any calculation so it is easy to get to the answer. Let me know if you are not able to see that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please elaborate why D is circumcenter of △BCE.

Comment: $CD = DE$ and $\angle CDE = 2 \angle B$. The angle subtended by a chord at the center of a circle is twice the angle subtended on the circle.

Comment: Its my bad that I didn't understand your answer. I need to learn more as your answer is higher than my level of knowledge. Your answer is also 4.58. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint: See picture. Make sure you understand how each sides are calculated and make use of similar triangles.

Comment: Hi, please elaborate how you get EG?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other answers. Identify $D$ as circumcenter of $\triangle BEC$. With more angle chasing, $AC$ is tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle BEC$.

By secant-tangent theorem $AC^2=AE\cdot AB=60$

Denote side of square by $x$. Then by Pythagoras in $\triangle EAF$,

$$x^2 + (\sqrt{60}-x)^2=6^2$$

There'll be two values of $x$. Two squares are possible as explained by @peterwhy in the comment below the question. Obtain $x^2$.

Comment: The equation gives two answer: 2.14 and 5.60, that is not the same as 4.58. I have checked the answer by drawing the problem using Geogebra.

Comment: @Zonouzi This equation calculates side of square. For area you have to compute side$^2$.

Comment: That is why I couldn't find any issue in your answer, that's my fault, sorry and thank you for letting me to know.

Answer (score 0):

Let the square have side $L$ and consider triangles $AEF$ and $BCE$.

Simply using the sum of angles in a triangle we see that $\angle AEF =\angle BCE=X$ say.
Then
$$6\sin X=\sqrt{36-L^2}, \sqrt2L\sin X=4\sin 45.$$
Eliminating $\sin X$ gives a quadratic for the area $L^2$,  $$L^2(36-L^2)=12^2,$$
with solutions $L^2=18\pm 6\sqrt 5.$

Comment: L=18 - 6*sqrt(5) gives the answer, thank you.

Comment: Yes, the other solution is the 'acute case'. It is an interesting general result that the product of the two possible values for $L$ is half the product of the two given lengths.

Comment: Product of the two values of L is 144, hence its square root is 12, exactly half the product of the two given lengths, that is 24. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Did you noticed it at this problem, or it has a known background? If there is a history behind it, can you point me to it?

Comment: No, I thought the problem looked worth solving in general and that was the result. The solution I have given works just as easily with a and b as with 6 and 4.